# One method requires a DLL, an identical one doesn't

Tags: c#, dll

I have two methods for retrieving data from Active Directory. They are both identical except for a string constant between the two.

Calling method A from another project gives a build error and requires that I add the Directory Services .dll to that project, but calling method B does not.

Why is this?

Method A:

```
    public static string GetUserDisplayName(string username)
    {
        var user = FindUser(username);
        return GetPropertyOrNull(user, "displayName");
    }
```

Method B:

```
    public static string GetUserEmailAddress(string username)
    {
        var user = FindUser(username);
        return GetPropertyOrNull(user, "mail").ToLower();
    }
```

Context:

```
    private static SearchResult FindUser(string username)
    {
        var dSearch = GetDirectorySearcher();
        username = username.Split('\\').Last().Trim(); //removes domain
        dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + username + "))";
        dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        var result = dSearch.FindOne();
        return result;
    }

    private static string GetPropertyOrNull(SearchResult searchResult, string propertyName)
    {
        if (searchResult == null) return null;
        if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
        {
            var prop = searchResult.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
            return prop;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Other project makes these calls:

```
//this line is fine
var submitterEmail = ADUtil.GetUserEmailAddress(submitterUserName);
//this line throws a compiler error. removing it, the project builds
var submitterCN = ADUtil.GetUserDisplayName(submitterUserName);
```

Why is this, and how can I get around it? I'd like to avoid needing the DLL in my other project.

(Note: I also tried adding `ToLower()` to method A to no avail.

Comment: I've seen several complaints about this, lately.  The C# compiler has been getting more demanding, in an undiagnosable way, about finding out more about indirect dependencies.  Not something that's in any way prescribed in the C# language spec, there are no formal rules about this.  There's no signal at all in these snippets, but expectation is that a type from System.DirectoryServices is leaking out in your public interface.  Not necessarily in just these methods.  You really *do* need this assembly at runtime, there's very little point in not just adding the reference.

Comment: hrm, that's a pain. it'll be interesting to see if this happens with Roslyn. Thanks for the info. It's not a big deal to add the reference, I'd just prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Method A had an overload that takes a parameter that's only present in that dll.

In the code below, `SearchResult` is from the DirectoryServices dll. Changing this method from public to private, or changing the name fixed the issue.

```
    public static string GetUserDisplayName(SearchResult user)
    {
        return GetPropertyOrNull(user, "displayName");
    }
```

I suppose that makes sense, I suppose the compiler tries to account for any overloads for that named method.